# Can ‘as’ be the object of a preposition?

Tags: pronouns

In the sentence, can ‘as’ be the object of preposition?

> I understand what it is to have a blended family. I can empathize with people who've lost loved ones. I think that's part of our experience of learning from **as** when we overcome things like that.

This was uttered during a monologue in [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaTS-g_Gf4k).  (You can find her saying this between  2:56 and 3:07).

Comment: The last sentence is ungrammatical: "part **of** our" and "learning from **overcoming** things like that" are what should be there. Finally, I don't think the context of the sentence is sufficient to make it meaningful. Things like **that**? Does "that" refer to the death of a loved one? I think that the style of this sentence is quite cold. Is a "blended family" anything like a "microwaved baby"?

Comment: _"I think part of our experience comes from learning, by overcoming tragedies like that."_ (I think that's what you're trying to say.) Anyhow, when writing questions like this, you should also say where you got the sentence from. Did you write it? Find it in a blog? Read it in a book? See it in a scientific or legal journal? Tell the source, as _context_ may well affect the right answer.

Comment: Those sentences are from a YouTube channel (2:56~3:07): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaTS-g_Gf4k&feature=g-all-u

Comment: Would you please check it up?

Comment: (1) Put these clarifications in the question itself, not the comments, so that others who read the question don't have to read through comments to get the full context. (2) This is from a video, where she's not reading from a teleprompter, so you wouldn't expect everything to necessarily be grammatically correct. People misspeak sometimes. (3) I think she says "is", not "as", which makes the sentence much more clear.

Comment: Might it be *us* instead of *as*?

Comment: @SF: I think it's an "is." I think the speaker meant to say something like, "Part of our learning experience **is** when we overcome things like that." or "That's what we learn **from** – when we overcome things like that," but the possible wordings blended together as she struggled for the right way to phrase it, and we ended up with a "**from is**" in the transcript. You can tell she's faltering a little at 3:04 when she glances down to regain her train of thought.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I’ve read what you left about how to put on questions. I’ll keep in mind. And I have a question. Can I upload a question asking for checking what I took dictation from YouTube videos etc? If not, would you please introduce the kind of website, if you know?

Comment: Question lacks any evidence of research effort before posting. This question can be improved by researching the answer and including the results in the question. As it stands, voting to close "not a real question".

Comment: @Listenever: Proofreading is expressly considered off-topic, so I wouldn't post that here. Maybe answers.com? It's a general-purpose site; insofar as I know, they don't have such restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some commenters have noted, the sentence you provide is not grammatically correct. If the sentence you provide is a correct transcription of what the speaker said, then it's an example of the way in which spoken language is often not grammatically correct, because people misspeak, hesitate, start saying one thing but link it to something else, and so on.

In general, *as* is a conjunction or an adverb, and such words cannot on their own be the objects of a preposition. However, *as* can introduce clauses that are the object of a preposition:

> Collect money from as many people as possible

So, you might find *as* following a preposition, but it will not stand alone as the object of the preposition. Instead it will be part of a clause, and that clause will be the object of the preposition.